# Change the default "new folder" icon

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I want to set a default icon for all the new folders created in windows by  a **Right Click > New > Folder**.

Is this possible in windows 8.1?

I have googled a lot and found a way to change the icon for all  the windows folders, which is not my case.

actually, I want to set my data folders with a special icon, which is different from the System Folder icon.. Until now, I do this manually by creating each folder and change its icon, and I wondered if it can be done with smart way.. Any way.. It looks like I should do it manually for ever..

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible. You're asking to change all new folders into an icon which is set to a path which all previous folders and new folders will grab an icon from.

Comment: What would you need this for anyway? If every new folder uses that icon, doesn't it kind of become the default icon?

Comment: @BradlySpicer I wouldn't be surprised if this was in the registry somewhere. After two decades, who really knows what's in it. I mean it doesn't seem like something Microsoft would hardcode for each version when they get new art.

Comment: @Louis I just assume it's one specific path to the icon they set for all folders. Thus creating a new one for a specific folder would be very difficult